# www url creates an error, non-www works

Tags: apache-2.2

In my server, when I access a page without www, it loads correctly. But if I try with www, I get cgi-sys error.

I am using CentOS release 6.8
Apache/2.2.31

I believe that 'rewrite_module' is enabled in apache.

```
   # httpd -M | grep rew
   Syntax OK
   rewrite_module (static)
```

It doesn't show up in phpinfo(). Does it matter?

my httpd.conf:

```
<VirtualHost IP:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias  example.com
    DocumentRoot /path/to/folder

    <Directory "/path/to/folder">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </Directory>
```

I have set this in htaccess:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I have checked that htaccess is read: I added a faulty line, and I saw that I get an error 500.

still www doesn't work. any ideas?

## RESOLUTION

It was a browser cache problem. Clearing the cache and cookies solved it

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: a default error page from cpanel: cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi: "SORRY! If you are the owner of this website, please contact your hosting provider. It is possible you have reached this page because: The IP address has changed. There has been a server misconfiguration. The site may have moved to a different server"

Comment: Sorry, we can't help with cPanel.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It has been a browser cache issue. @Dre's answer also might have helped a bit. I saw that you marked it as off-topic, and I think that it would be good if you leave this question. I lost few hours trying to find solution, I read many possible solutions, but none suggested clearing the cache. If you can, help future generations and leave this question.

Answer (score 1):

You should update your ServerAlias value to include each alias you want to use. Simply separate each value with a space:

```
ServerAlias  www.example.com example.com
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It didn't work.. any other idea?